# WPF Fluent Ribbon Compile Problems

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, ribbon, fluent, fluent-ribbon

I am trying to compile the latest Version of the Fluent Ribbon (e709a1f6bb2e) for .NET 3.5 with Visual Studio 2008 but I got several problems with that. 
After removing the empty (?) Office2007 Theme and the Metro Theme (which created problems), the Compiler still displays an Error with the `Themes/generic.xaml` and the `Themes/Office2010/Black.xaml`...

```
"The tag "ObjectToImageConverter" does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:Fluent'."
```

As you can see the Namespace is added to the Xaml, and I can find the public `ObjectToImageConverter-class` in the solution.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?